# Plot the map (raster file) in R, ggplot2 in particular

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, raster, r-raster

I want to plot the map of climate zones of Australia. Relevant files (ASCII file) have been downloded from: http://www.bom.gov.au/web01/ncc/www/climatology/climate-classification/kpngrp.zip

The orginal map looks like this.

[image]

But when I used the ASCII file to re-plot this map, I cannot make it. The used code is:

```
library(ggplot2);library(raster)
r<-raster("kpngrp.txt")
plot(r)
```

How do I fix this to plot the map?

Comment: There are way more than 6 levels in that raster `unique(getValues(r))`

Comment: Thanks for your information. Do you the method to using the raster file to make the map?

Answer (score 2):

You first have to properly read your dataset, which is not a raster file, but a txt. The first lines of the header provide information about "format" and georeferencing:

> ncols           1681
> nrows           1361
> xllcorner       112
> yllcorner -44
> cellsize      0.025
> NODATA_value  -9999

to properly read the data and convert it to a `raster` object, you can therefore do:

```
infile <- "/home/lb/Temp/buttami/kpngrp.txt"
data <- as.matrix(read.table(infile, skip = 6)) 
data[data == -9999] = NA
rr <- raster(data, crs = "+init=epsg:4326")
extent(rr) = c(112, 112+0.025*1681, -44, -44+0.025*1361)

> rr
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1361, 1681, 2287841  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.025, 0.025  (x, y)
extent      : 112, 154.025, -44, -9.975  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 42  (min, max)
```

now, to plot it you can use several approaches. However, to get something nice you'll first have to remove the "ocean" data by masking with a vector shapefile:

```
adm <- getData("GADM", country="AUS", level=1)
rr = mask(rr, adm)
plot(rr)
```

[image]

NOte that the plot shows more "colors" than your example, since I think they aggregated the Koppen regions by larger "categories". TO obtain a map osimilar to that you will have to "join" several values of the original ASCII in a smaller number of classes.